# SQL Server : function works in one view, returns permission error in another

Tags: sql-server, permissions, execute

We have a simple function that counts business days between two dates (excludes weekends, holidays).

In one view, it works fine but in another view, it returns:

> The EXECUTE permission was denied on the object 'fx_CountDaysBetween_V2', database 'xxxx', schema 'dbo'

The good view calls  the function with this line

```
CASE 
   WHEN r.Current_Status_Code IN (2, 3, 4, 7) 
      THEN dbo.fx_CountDaysBetween_V2(CONVERT(DATE, PA.Create_Date), CONVERT(DATE, GETUTCDATE())) ELSE NULL END AS DaysInQueue,
```

The bad view has this:

```
dbo.fx_CountDaysBetween_V2(CONVERT(DATE, rh.Submitted_Date), ISNULL(CONVERT(DATE, rc.Completed_Date), GETUTCDATE())) AS SLA,
```

The person with the issue does NOT have execute rights. This looks like a problem but then why would one work and not the other. The function is also used in other areas/views as well without issue

Answer (score 0):

Do the good view and the bad view have the same owner? If not, I'd suspect ownership chaining  is causing this - look at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tutorial-ownership-chains-and-context-switching?view=sql-server-ver15

or

https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1778/ownership-chaining-in-sql-server-security-feature-or-security-risk/

for a full explanation, but basically if you give a user permissions on an object like a view or stored procedure, the owner passes that permission on to other things by the same owner.

If that's not what's happening, examine the dependency chain (effectively the call stack) to see if there was a user context switch between where the user first starts making the query and the call to dbo.fx_CountDaysBetween. Look for "EXECUTE AS" in one of the views/functions/whatever. Note that it can be a stand alone statement or be part of the definition, so it can be hard to spot.

Those are the 2 most common reasons I can think of, if it's neither of those comment on this and update your post to include ownership information and maybe insert a logging statement to record the current user context just before the call.